# clicking on link reopens div once closed

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slidetoggle

I have jquery hiding links. I have it so the user can click on the button which closes the list of links underneath. Which makes another list underneath it move up.

Now problem is, when the user clicks on a link, the div that was closed is opened up again.

Is there way to save the state of the div? So if it's closed, keep it closed if the user clicks on a link.

Thanks, just started learning jquery. Here is my code:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu_toggle a").click(function() {
            $("#menu_toggle a").toggle();

                if($('#secondary').is(':visible')) {
                    $("#secondary").slideUp("slow");
                        stop(true,true);
                } else {
                    $("#secondary").slideDown("slow");
                    stop(true,true);
                }
        });

            $("#admin_toggle a").click(function() {
                $("#admin_toggle a").toggle();              
                if($('#admin').is(':visible')) {
                    $("#admin").slideUp("slow");
                    stop(true,true);
                } else {
                    $("#admin").slideDown("slow");
                    stop(true,true);
                }

            });

    });
```

here it is on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYbr6/)

now it when I click on the links with # attribute to href it doesn't do anything but on my local server it does.

Comment: Put a working example up on jsfiddle.net and post the link here so we can take alook

Answer (score 0):

Where do the links point to? Are there any events attached to those links, such as onclick or onhashchange? If so, please post those event handlers as well.

All the links in your jsfiddle code point to "#", which obviously doesn't do anything. Is that the same with your actual code, or do the links point to other pages? If clicking on one of those links causes the browser to refresh the current page or navigate to another page, it's no surprise that the menus reset themselves when the new page is loaded. You'll have to use a cookie or some sort of server-side scripting to remember the state of the menu across different page views.